# How to use constant imported from outside of test file (Jest, Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to check if a Button have a `href` value that is the same with what was defined in a `const` outside of the test file. The constants are `formUrl` and `overviewUrl`.

Anyone know how to solve this error? or is there another way to achieve what I want to?

```js
import { cleanup, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import ComingSoon from "./page";
import { formUrl, overviewUrl } from "constant/urls";

// Note: running cleanup afterEach is done automatically for you in @testing-library/react@9.0.0 or higher
// unmount and cleanup DOM after the test is finished.
afterEach(cleanup);

it("Check if content is correct", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<ComingSoon />);
  expect(
    getByText(
      "Be the first to know about our upcoming launch. Subscribe now for exclusive updates, sneak peeks, and special offers!"
    )
  ).toBeTruthy();
  expect(getByText("Remind me")).toBeTruthy();
  expect(getByText("Remind me").getAttribute("href")).toBe(formUrl);

  expect(getByText("Take me home")).toBeTruthy();
  expect(getByText("Take me home").getAttribute("href")).toBe(overviewUrl);
});
```

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'constant/urls' from 'app/coming-soon/page.test.tsx'

       6 | // unmount and cleanup DOM after the test is finished.
       7 | afterEach(cleanup);
    >  8 |
         | ^
       9 | it("Check if content is correct", () => {
      10 |   const { getByText } = render(<ComingSoon />);
      11 |   expect(

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/coming-soon/page.test.tsx:8:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the path is `<Your Project Name>/src/contant/urls.ts` and you want jest to recognize the path alias. Add [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) configuration to the `jest.config.js`:

```js
 moduleNameMapper: {
   '^constant/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/constant/$1',
 },
```

Comment: I got this error `Could not locate module constant/urls mapped as: **/**/**/**/**/app/constant/$1`.

Comment: @jted95 Can you show the folder structure? Please edit your post with folder structure

Comment: hey, thank you. I just recheck the value in `moduleNameMapper` url, it was wrong. just fixed it and it works. thanks a lot.